# Pandas complex filtering

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas.DataFrame() object like below

```
start, end
    5, 9
    6, 11
    13, 11
    14, 11
    15, 17
    16, 17
    18, 17
    19, 17
    20, 24
    22, 26
```

"end" has to always be > "start"
So, I need to filter it from when the "end" values becomes < "start" till the next row where they are again are back to normal.

In above example, I need:

1.

```
13,11
15,17
```

2.

```
18,17
20,24
```

Edit: (updated)
Think of these as timestamps in seconds. So I can find that it took 2 seconds in both scenario to recover back.

I can do this in iterating the data, but does Pandas have a better way ?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do: remove those rows?  Find groups of rows beginning where `start > end` and continuing up to and including the next row where `start < end`?

Comment: Yes. Find group of rows, so I can find out the deltas between them. Will update question for more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You could use panda's [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) to find the rows where `start < end`. Then if you [reset the index](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) you can calculate the difference between the original indices that act as the upper and lower bounds delta between rows where `start > end`.

For example you could do something like the following:

```
# A = starts, B = ends
df = pd.DataFrame({'B' : [9, 11, 11, 11, 17, 17, 17, 17, 24, 26],
                   'A': [5, 6, 13, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19, 20, 22]})

# use boolean indexing
df = df[df['A'] < df['B']].reset_index()

# calculate the difference of each row's "old" index to determine delta
diffs = df['index'].diff()

# create a column to show deltas
df['delta'] = diffs

print(diffs)
print(df)
```

The `diffs` data frame looks like:

```
0   NaN
1     1
2     3
3     1
4     3
5     1
Name: index, dtype: float64
```

Notice the `NaN` value since the `diff()` method subtracts the previous row from the current row, but since the first row has no previous row it marks a `NaN`. One must only look at the first value of  the `index` column to calculate the delta in the case that the first arbitrary number of `n starts` were `> ends`.

The fully augmented data frame would then look like:

```
   index   A   B  delta
0      0   5   9    NaN
1      1   6  11      1
2      4  15  17      3
3      5  16  17      1
4      8  20  24      3
5      9  22  26      1
```

If you wish to delete any of the extraneous columns you can use the `del` method like so:

```
del col1, col2, col3, etc..
```